# Sonata list fields with joined one-to-many entity field columns

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I have a Staff entity in my db that is connected to various Company entities (many-to-many) through a bridge table (StaffCompany), that contains further info about the association (`Staff -< StaffCompany >- Company`).

When listing I always filter the list through a query so that there's only the currently selected Company's members visible.

Now I would like to show some of these additional StaffCompany info in the list fields alongside some Staff info (assuming that there's always a single relevant StaffCompany entity to join).

How could I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

you should use a pivot table.  so basically what this means is you have your staff table and the entities table and this table will have id's of these 2 tables so employee id 1 => entity 1
employee id 1 => entity 2

and then you can join this table with your individual tables and get the full details.

Comment: yeah I'm doing that right now with the StaffCompany entity (though I call them bridge tables) - my question is about the sonata implementation actually...

Answer (score 0):

You could add one or many [custom row cell template](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/list_field_definition.html#custom-template) and do you want inside, that is to say show the SatffCompany info.

Comment: Yeah, but it would also be nice if I didn't have to do additional queries at every row. Rather, it would already be joined into the main entity...

Comment: I'm not sure that's necessary, mostly if you use `staffCompanies` in the list field name but you can customize the list query to make the join, see [official doc](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_list.html#customizing-the-query-used-to-generate-the-list)